# Can Health-Releated Services be a Business Expense?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, small-business

I own a small S-Corp. I am considering subscribing to a monthly meditation service ($5/month) to help me with my focus, creativity, etc.

1 - Can I charge this on my business account?

2 - Is this tax deductible as a business expense?

Answer (score 2):

Chris, since you own your own company, nobody can stop you from charging your personal expenses to your business account. IRS is not a huge fan of mixing business and personal expenses and this practice might indicate to them that you are not treating your business seriously, and it should classify your business as a hobby.

IRS defines deductible business expense as being both: ordinary AND necessary. Meditation is not an ordinary expense (other S-corps do not incur such expense.) It is not a necessary expense either. Therefore, you cannot deduct this expense. http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Deducting-Business-Expenses

Comment: Charging personal expenses to the corporation may very well pierce the corp limited liability veil, and render the whole entity useless.